# jsonapi-resources cross versions relationships

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, jsonapi-resources

How can I add a new version of a resource without duplicating his related resources and controllers?

Lets say I have an API described by the following routing:

```
namespace :api do
  namespace :v1 do
    jsonapi_resources :contacts
    jsonapi_resources :phone_numbers
  end
end

class Api::V1::ContactResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attributes :first_name, :last_name
  has_one :phone_number
end
```

I want to add new version of my `ContactResource` without duplicating the `PhoneNumberResource` and `PhoneNumberController`, is there a way to do something like:

```
class Api::V2::ContactResource < JSONAPI::Resource
  attributes :full_name
  has_one :phone_number, related_class: Api::V1::PhoneNumberResource
end
```

I'm working on a project with many related resources and I don't want to duplicate all of them, any suggestions?